# Consent Form with DocuSign for Salesforce without Sending Email

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

We have a scenario where a user needs to click on a link and a Consent Form in a .pdf format will open. Once the document is opened, the user will be able to sign the form using DocuSign. Upon clicking [Finished] button, the signed form will be uploaded in the system. Is this possible with DocuSign?

P/S: We are not looking into sending to email nor In Person Signing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use DocuSign embedded Signing, which does not send any email nor is In-Person signing. You can check embedded Signing here, https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/embedded_signing.html

Also you can use API (using Polling - Not recommended) or DS Connect to get alert when Signer has completed the signing ceremony, once you know that signer has completed the signing ceremony then you can pull the signed form to your system.

Comment: Thank you so much Amit :) I will look into your suggestion. One quick question: Does PowerForm works the same as per your suggestion above?

Comment: Yes, you can get signing completion message via Connect for Powerform users as well. And if you have direct Powerform (with email validation checkbox clicked) will not receive any email and directly Signing screen will open.